# Migrating Exchange 2016

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2013, exchange-2016, microsoft

I wanna migrate from exchange 2010 to 2016 
now my 2010 is running and I wanna install 2016 on another server but same domain without creating a new schema for it cut later I will transfer all data from 2010 to 2016 but I get error so can i skip that errors while installing 2016 or what is the steps to install 2016 without link it to Active directory : 
Error : 
This computer doesn't belong to a valid Active Directory site. Check the site and subnet definitions.
For more information, visit: http://technet.microsoft.com/library(EXCHG.150)/ms.exch.setupreadiness.InvalidADSite.aspx

The Active Directory schema isn't up-to-date, and this user account isn't a member of the 'Schema Admins' and/or
'Enterprise Admins' groups.
For more information, visit: http://technet.microsoft.com/library(EXCHG.150)/ms.exch.setupreadiness.SchemaUpdateRequired
.aspx

Setup encountered a problem while validating the state of Active Directory: Could not find information about the local
site. This can be caused by incorrect configuration of subnets or sites or by replication latency. See the Exchange
setup log for more information on this error.
For more information, visit: http://technet.microsoft.com/library(EXCHG.150)/ms.exch.setupreadiness.AdInitErrorRule.aspx

The forest functional level of the current Active Directory forest is not Windows Server 2003 native or later. To
install Exchange Server 2016, the forest functional level must be at least Windows Server 2003 native.
For more information, visit: http://technet.microsoft.com/library(EXCHG.150)/ms.exch.setupreadiness.ForestLevelNotWin200
3Native.aspx

Either Active Directory doesn't exist, or it can't be contacted.
For more information, visit: http://technet.microsoft.com/library(EXCHG.150)/ms.exch.setupreadiness.CannotAccessAD.aspx

The Exchange Server setup operation didn't complete. More details can be found in ExchangeSetup.log located in the
:\ExchangeSetupLogs folder.

Answer (score 1):

When upgrading from Exchange 2010 to 2016 you should definitely lift the AD and Forest levels and schemas to (at least) a supported level. Exchange and the Active Directory are very tightly integrated.

Lifting the AD and Forest levels requires that you've set up new enough domain controllers in your forest, and that you've demoted currently unsupported domain controllers (Windows Server 2003 and older) - this of course is something you should do anyway.

Once you've installed Exchange 2016 and configured it to suit your environment, you can start moving DNS pointers to the new server, which will act as a proxy for traffic to mailboxes that still reside on the Exchange 2010 environment. With that done, you can start moving the mailboxes proper. 
After all traffic and all mailboxes are migrated, clean up your environment and remove the Exchange 2010 server.

Answer (score 0):

Is the machine a domain-joined, and do you login as a domain user with required permissions?

You can’t bypass the readiness check when installation. It would continue until the requirements and prerequisites pass.

The target server must be a member of an Active Directory domain.

The account that you use to install Exchange requires the following permissions:

“Enterprise Admins group membership”, “Schema Admins group membership”, “Exchange Organization Management role group membership”

Please refer to the article for more details about installation:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/plan-and-deploy/deploy-new-installations/install-mailbox-role?view=exchserver-2019

Comment: hi Dear I did all of this my main issue is that in my AD there is the current exchange 2010 schema that doesn't allow to create a new one and I do not wanna delete it I have a software to transfer all data from 2010 to 2016 but first I have to configure 2016 and make it ready

Comment: Please look at this article about coexistence requirement:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31663.install-exchange-2016-in-exchange-2010-co-existence.aspx  
Make sure you use the latest RU for all the Exchange 2010 servers, and  match the Domain requirements.

Comment: dears I just want to know how to install 2 exchange server in same domain and active directory because I do not want to remove the old one till install the new one and transfer data